# Editing a child entity doesn't remove old rows from table, it always adds new ones in entity framework ASP.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a teacher entity that has a child entity of ICollection called YogaClasses. When I modify the list of YogaClasses for a teacher and save, entity framework adds the new rows of YogaClasses to the table 'YogaClass' but it doesn't remove or edit the old rows. So I'm left with double the data. Shouldn't "context.SaveChanges()" in my repo be smart enough to know to delete removed classes and add the new ones (edit), not just add new ones?

In my controller I have something like this for a Teacher edit.

```
string userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
Teacher teacher = teacherRepository.Find(userId);
//other code left out here
teacher.YogaClasses = GetSelectedClasses(Request.Form[2]);
// other stuff here
teacherRepository.Save();
```

In my reposity I have this;

```
public void Save()
{
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Here is my teacher and YogaClass entity

```
public class Teacher
{
    public int TeacherId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<YogaClass> YogaClasses { get; set; }
}
public class YogaClass
{
    public int YogaClassId { get; set; }
    [Index]
    [Required]
    public int TeacherRefId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("TeacherRefId")]
    public virtual Teacher Teacher { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: please post GetSelectedClasses() method

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `Attach` method of the context and pass in your existing `teacher` object and then make the changes and call `SaveChanges` method. From your code it is not clear what is your context, so hard to give working code. [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592676.aspx) is a link explaining how to add/modify

You said you need to modify YogaClasses, so from this what I assume is a Teacher object already has some YogaClasses entries and you want to update some of those entries. What you need to do is, have a list of ids of YogaClasses that you need to modify then iterate on that ids list and in that iteration loop find the existing yogaClass and attach it to the context, modify it and then call save changes (preferablly when all the changes are done so that it is not a performance hit)

Here is a suodocode for this

```
 UpdateTeacher(int teacherId)
    {
        var teacher = teacherRepository.Find(teacherId);
        UpdateYoga(teacher);
    }

    private void UpdateYoga(Teacher teacher)
    {
        foreach(var yoga in teacher.YogaClasses)
        {
            db.Context.Attach(yoga);
            yoga.YogaStyle = whatEverValue;
        }
        db.context.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Comment: can you please ellaborate a little more here. would I nee to pass a teacher object to attach or a yogaclass to a teacher context?

Comment: even with this solution, which I just tried, no rows are deleted, just added to the YogaClass table

Comment: i have tried to explain it with some example, please see the updated answer and let me know if that helps in someway or needs improvement.

Comment: I think you are confused here. My context is a teacher entity. You can't attach a yogaclass to a teacher context. you can only attach a yogaclass to a yogaclass context

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is the relationship has not been loaded at the time you set `teacher.YogaClasses`. So when you set `teacher.YogaClasses`, it assumes the new relationship will be added. (lazyloading is still a bit late in this case). The solution is somehow you ensure to load all the relationships first (using either `Include` or some fake access to trigger lazyloading first), then you set the new value normally:

```
//fake access to trigger lazy loading (of course this works only if 
//lazy loading is enabled)
var someClasses = teacher.YogaClasses;
teacher.YogaClasses = GetSelectedClasses(Request.Form[2]);
```

You can also clear the old classes and add new ones with a foreach loop:

```
teacher.YogaClasses.Clear();
foreach(var c in GetSelectedClasses(Request.Form[2])){
   teacher.YogaClasses.Add(c);
}
```

Comment: I tried this approach 'teacher.YogaClasses.Clear()', but it doesn't remove the rows from 'YogaClass' it just nulls out the 'Teacher_TeacherId' column

Comment: @user1186050 so what about the first approach?

Comment: nope, it did the same thing as your other solution. It nulls out the teacher_teacherId column and the rows still exist in the table.

Comment: @user1186050 I guess your `teacher_teacherId` column is not required (allows NULL). It should be marked as not allow Null. In that case EF will auto cascade delete the Yoga class.

Comment: this column is autogenerated by EF, so what would I have to change in my code first entity "YogaClass" to make that not nullable?

Comment: @user1186050 `teacher_teacherId` should be a foreign-key column referencing the `teacherId` in `Teacher` table. I don't think it's auto-generated. You explicitly excluded that property from `YogaClass`. If possible try modifying that column (in the YogaClass table) at ***database level***.  If you explicitly add a property of `teacher_teacherId` in `YogaClass`, then try applying the attribute `[Required]` on that property.

Comment: I meant it's autogenerated by EF I didn't create that column, EF did. Remember, I'm using a code first approach, so no db acces (theoretically!)

Comment: @user1186050 can you add a property named `TeacherId` to the class `YogaClass`? I'm not familiar with code first but if that property is added, you can try using `[Required]` attribute (and hope the generated column will have Allows NULL unchecked). Also a `[ForeignKey]` attribute should be used.

Comment: trying that right now. I think this will work. Hold on for response.

Comment: You may have to add 2 properties: `TeacherId` of type `int` (with [Required] attribute) and `Teacher` of type `Teacher` (with [ForeignKey("TeacherId")] attribute). I doubt there may be some easier solution (such as adding just one property or even using `Fluent API`) but as I said I'm not familiar with code-first.

Comment: ok I added a explicit name and foreign key to the table yogaclass and here is what I received with your first solution. "The operation failed: The relationship could not be changed because one or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable. When a change is made to a relationship, the related foreign-key property is set to a null value. If the foreign-key does not support null values, a new relationship must be defined, the foreign-key property must be assigned another non-null value, or the unrelated object must be deleted."

Comment: sorry I attempted your second solution. Now I will try your first again but I have a feeling I will get the same thing

Comment: yup same thing with both of your solutions.

Comment: @user1186050 have you tried clearing all records in `YogaClass` table having NULL teacherID? It is going to some new issue related to Code first. After the first time running code, you now should have a new database created, so I'm not sure how code first deals with it.

Comment: @user1186050 you should update what you changed to the `YogaClass` in your question, I believe someone else may come across this question and help. The code I give in my answer is in fact correct but your code-first setup has another problem at first.

Comment: @user1186050 you have 2 properties ending with `Id` in `YogaClass` (YogaClassId and TeacherRefId), so as far as I know those will be understood as composite key for YogaClass. I think you need to use the `[Key]` attribute applied on `YogaClassId`).

Comment: let me give that a try, hold on for response

Comment: @user1186050 then I've run out of idea. Next time when you have another project, try setting up the codefirst like this and using the code I posted here to update the navigation property (of collection). Your current project now may involve something called migration (all related to code-first which I've not experienced much).

Answer (score 0):

I have a dirty solution but it doesn't seem like it's the best one.

before I save the teacher context in my repo I can call this

```
public void DeleteYogaClasses(Teacher teacher)
{
    foreach (var yogaClass in teacher.YogaClasses.ToList())
    {
        context.Entry(yogaClass).State = EntityState.Deleted;
    }
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```